# libpng warning: extra compression data

Tags: c++, opencv, libpng

I'm using OpenCV `imdecode`, ORB feature extractor and ORB keypoint detector on an (considerably big) image dataset and I'm getting this warning:

```
libpng warning: extra compression data
```

Do you have any idea what kind of images trigger this warning in libpng?

Comment: One of the image has some extra data (I assume you are getting only one warning). You are speaking about a big database, you can print the image filename when loading and see which one is triggering the warning. Redirect your command output to a file so that you don't have problems to search afterwards (It might be that warning goes on stderr, you'll have to redirect also that)

Comment: What do you mean by extra data? Can you explain a bit more that part? @Antonio

Comment: First find the image causing generating that message, then everything might be more clear. It might be corrupted for example.